# Como validar componentes filho utilizando VeeValidate no VueJs?

Tags: vue.js

Pessoal me vi na seguinte situação, eu tenho um componente pai que chama Account e ele engloba vários componentes como AccountAddress, AccountPhone, etc... Cada um desses componentes possui alguns inputs que necessitam validação, eu já rodei a documentação do VeeValidate, o que mais se aproximou foi o ValidationProvider, porém eu não consegui aplicar no meu caso, segue o código que estou trabalhando, este é o Account:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- DADOS PESSOAIS -->
        <vx-card
                title="Dados pessoais">
            <div class="vx-row mb-6">
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/2 w-full mb-2">
                    <vs-select v-validate="'required'"
                               label="Tipo pessoa"
                               name="account[type]"
                               v-model="account.type">
                        <vs-select-item :key="index"
                                        :value="item.id"
                                        :text="item.name"
                                        v-for="(item,index) in accountType"/>
                    </vs-select>
                </div>
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/2 w-full mb-2">
                    <vs-input class="w-full"
                              v-validate="'required'"
                              placeholder="ex.: João Silva"
                              name="account[name_company]"
                              v-model="account.name_company"
                              :label="getLabel('name_company')"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="vx-row mb-6">
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/2 w-full mb-2">
                    <vs-input class="w-full"
                              icon-pack="feather"
                              icon="icon-mail"
                              icon-no-border
                              placeholder="ex.: 000.000.000-00"
                              name="account[cpf_cnpj]"
                              v-mask="getMask('cpf_cnpj')"
                              v-model="account.cpf_cnpj"
                              :label="getLabel('cpf_cnpj')"/>
                </div>
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/2 w-full mb-2">
                    <vs-input class="w-full"
                              icon-pack="feather"
                              icon="icon-mail"
                              icon-no-border
                              placeholder="ex.: 00.000.000-0"
                              name="account[rg_ie]"
                              v-model="account.rg_ie"
                              :label="getLabel('rg_ie')"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </vx-card>

        <template v-if="account.type == 'Jurídica'">
            <vs-divider/>
            <account-responsible></account-responsible>
        </template>

        <template>
            <vs-divider/>
            <account-address></account-address>
        </template>

        <template v-if="account.type == 'Física'">
            <vs-divider/>
            <account-phone></account-phone>
        </template>

        <template v-if="account.type == 'Física'">
            <vs-divider/>
            <account-email></account-email>
        </template>

        <vs-button @click="submitForm" type="gradient" class="w-full mt-6" color="#7367F0" gradient-color-secondary="#CE9FFC">Salvar</vs-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Quando eu dou submit, apenas os inputs no componente pai são validados, mesmo os inputs nos componentes filhos tendo as regras especificadas.

**Resolvido injetando a dependência do validate, respondi com a solução.**

Comment: Olá, teria como postar o código do componente filho? Eu criaria a validação no componente filho que retornasse para o pai se os dados dele estão validados

Comment: Então, a lógica de validação ta em cada componente, vou editar o post e colocar, mas a minha dúvida é como eu iria perguntar ao componente se tá tudo ok

Comment: "minha dúvida é como eu iria perguntar ao componente se tá tudo ok"... me parece um trabalho para eventos.. você poderia emitir um evento dizendo sobre a validade do campo.

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado pela ajuda, resolvi injetando a dependência mesmo, o problema era que eu estava sobrescrevendo a instância em um outro componente e aí ele não conseguiu receber o evento para validar.
Quanto a sugestão do @fernandosavio, não é uma opção ruim, mas como a aplicação é grande eu acho que ficaria algo meio díficil de manter.

Comment: Guilherme, seria melhor você criar uma resposta com a sua solução e aceitá-la. Veja em [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue a solução:

- Desativei a injeção automática do vee-validate:

```
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {inject: false})
```

- Injetei a instância nos componentes que eu tenho interesse em validar:

```
export default {
    inject: ['$validator'],
}
```

Outra observação, eu estava tendo problemas para mostrar os erros nos componentes que estavam dentro de um escopo, necessário especificar na bag de errors:

```
<span class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('nome_campo', 'escopo') }}</span>
```

Resumindo, além de você economizar memória desativando a injeção automática do vee-validate, você consegue reaproveitar a bag de errors e validar todos os componentes em sua tela :)